Clean code PLC programming in Structured Text / HSM engine
I'm starting with PLC programming in Structured Text, specifically with Beckhoff Twincat 3, coming from an embedded programming background in C/C++ and some C#/Python for cross-platform development. I'm still in an orientation phase and try to make sense from what I read and what I experience while playing around with Twincat 3 and some hardware.
I've looked into a project written by a colleague of mine 3 years ago and it looks anything but "clean code". I hardly understand anything. There is a function block FB_DriveCommands.TcPOU with ~2600 lines of code!!!
My questions, one general and one more specific:

Is this normal/acceptable in the PLC world? Do I have to get used to it? If not, what is? What experience have you made with "clean code" approaches in PLC programming within your organization?
In particular, I see that the state machines in the mentioned project are always implemented via a CASE ... OF, even if they are complex, which leads to long, long sections of code where you have to lose track. Are there any libraries out there that support a different implementation, perhaps even for hierarchical state machines (HSM)? (Note: I've seen the Twincat function "UML state diagram" but sticking to structured text is a must).


Most PLC code is written by automation engineers, not software developers. They have other skills and knowledge than the 'clean code' you would like to achieve. CASE ...OF for state machine implementation and the simple software structure you describe are typical. You can always try to improve the code (base) and coding guidelines at your company and show the potential of these changes to your colleagues.

theres a good-ish example here from Beckhoff of what you can achieve with more modern techniques https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/100978955.html&id=7649550070152933723

If you work in structured text, there is no fundamental reason for code to be an ugly mess but "acceptable in the PLC world". PLC programs are software, structured text is not really different from C/Pascal along with some basic OO facilities.
Now, about state machines. In automation, people make code for machines, and machines have state, right? So what happens if you put machines and state together? Well, state machines of course. Sometimes, I feel the reason for the popularity of this concept in automation is its name.
When studying computer science, state machines are among the first things you are taught. You find out about their limitations, and you quickly move to more complex grammars for most of what you do, although state machines have specific use cases where they shine.
Out of the gate, the ever-evolving, unpredictable nature of physical systems and their multi-dimensional readings is very much not a modelling challenge I would associate with state machines. Quite the opposite in fact. I program machines, and never use a state machine.
Messy state machines may be a sign that a state machine is not the right abstraction.

"I program machines, and never use a state machine." -> Okay, so what do you use?

i can agree to that, i am a c# developer and automation engineer in both cases are different requierements, as @Fred mentioned, if your process is not cycle time critical a state machine is the way to go, if you have to deliver results in a certain pace (cycle time) than you would have for loops without state changes to spare cycle time, i have been in both worlds

The my code works with an "intent" (i.e. I want to move this part of the machine to this position), analyses the whole system and determines what it needs to do to achieve that. This could include starting a motor, moving other things, etc. There is no assumption made that the system is in any particular state due to past actions.  There can be many things happening in parallel, although my terse description might make it sound otherwise.

Funny thing is, once written, it kind of looks like coding a sequence of things (because in real life, when nothing unexpected happens, you will perform actions in what usually looks like a pre-determined sequence), but there are subtle differences that make it that whenever something unexpected occurs, it is like the code "goes back to a previous step" to fulfill the unexpectedly missing conditions. But this "backtracking" (which is not really backtraking) is not achieved by "transitioning to another state".

It depends what you are doing. In my line of work that kinds of non sequential programming would be a nightmare, conditional "go do this" if "this", particularly when doing robot operations is risky and provides more risks than benefits since it is next to impossible to predict everything that may happen, until one day it does(from personal experience). It would be interesting to see an example of what your code looks like, to get a better perspective of what you mean, maybe I am picturing it wrong.

For robotic applications, the PLC program calls on the robot program to execute paths (from a pre-determined list of paths IDs based on the application), and checks that the robot reports being at the expected position before starting a path. The PLC can interrupt an ongoing path (at any time), but does not dynamically generate a new path that can start from anywhere in space.  The robot program itself does not use the approach I described, either. When the robot is at a known position, the PLC can call any path that starts from there.

You could say the way the robot is managed can bee seen like a state machine, with presence at a known position being a state, execution of a given path being a state, and the logic of the PLC defining potential transitions, but it is not implemented as a typical state machine on either end.


Absolutely not normal or acceptable. The problem usually originates in PLC developer's background. Usually those who program PLC comes from Electrical Engineers or Automation Schematics Developers. And they start with FBD and LD and then move to ST. By that time, they think by categories of FBD, and they do not have any experience of text-based languages and they do not know good coding patterns. There are very few developers from the desktop or web development world. They come, taste it, and go away. This sector lacks good tools, debugging, old codes look like your description and salary level not higher than old job. With time you will see that Twincat IDE is a piece of crap and at the same time it is one of the best. That is simply say what other options are like for developers. This is a totally insulated world.
But no one make you write that kind of code.
So, the answer is yeas it is normal to see such a code, without separation of routines, business logic, computations, ... but it is not normal to code like that. If you are capable of building good program architectures with some levels of abstractions, that is great!

In Twincat we have 2 options for Sequential code. Either SFC (sort of UML diagram you've mentioned) or CASE in ST. Both have pros and cons. Me personally prefer CASE. At first yes, there are a lot of code in one file, but it is in one file. In case of SFC you open every step as a separate file which makes it even more difficult to navigate through. Also, in a CASE only one section works at one time. It is actually not a big code. Thus you usually look at a part of the code which is not big and ignore the rest. File might be big, but it is easy to navigate when you know what is going on. Especially when you debug, the code that is executed right now is only one option of a case which usually fits one page. And if not, you may make it, so it does.
I would start get used to CASE. You will see it a lot and you will use it a lot. Most of the time CASE is the most elegant way to solve the task.



Sorry, but I think your number 1 and 2 don't really go together. You never came across a more concise state machine implementation than with CASE? From C/C++, I am big fan of the QP framework

I did not find any other way to create simple sequential (step) programs as complex with divergence and convergence of different kinds. In IEC 61131-3 there is a special language for that SFC. But that is not a language but rather visual mapping. I have found it more complicated for me, some find it attractive. So I cannot advocate for it as well as against it. I only tell about my personal preferences. I think we think different what is state machine. I'll not be using that term. Bottomline. There are only 2 ways to create Step by Step programs and those either SFC or CASE. I like CASE.

"With time you will see that Twincat IDE is a piece of crap and at the same time it is one of the best." Thanks for the laughs, this is 100% correct :D

It is true there are some ways in which TwinCAT does not suck, but you see how hard they are working on each release to make sure one day this no longer is the case.
